# Retrieve Project's Members on BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Please, I'd like to retrieve the members of a specific project on BIM 360. Has anyone got any update on this issue?

something like e.g.:
https://admin.b360.autodesk.com/enterprise_projects/{project_id}/project_users

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Document Manager you can get it [using this approach](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-number-bim-360-projects-user).

Comment: Great stuff, Augusto! Thanks very much!